# Use WHERE clause to find a specific data type

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sqldatatypes

I am trying to find a way to query for a field that only contains a certain data type.

For example, I want to return all values from `dbo.tableA.ColumnA` that contain a string of 
`'___-___'` where each `_` is a numeric character. (The `-` is just a normal dash)

Also, I know this can be done using dynamic queries (which I am not experienced with) and I am aware that those high level queries probably require the creation of temp tables, which is something I can not do because I am only querying a snap-shot, and thus do not have Write access.

I have tried searching my pants off for an answer, with no luck. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`LIKE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) operator for this.

```
SELECT ColumnA 
FROM dbo.tableA
WHERE ColumnA LIKE '%[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
```

Comment: Thank you! This will certainly work, could I also do a similar search using WHERE ColumnA LIKE '%[a-z][a-z][a-z]%' to find alpha characters? Or am I just being to greedy

Comment: @AdamW. Yes you can though that is more collation dependant in what it will match. On a case sensitive collation it won't match `Z` (but will match `A`)

Comment: Hmm I am afraid that I don't fully understand what you mean by case sensative collation, I thought that all T-SQL coding was non-case sensative? Thank you for the answer btw

Comment: @AdamW.: Perhaps your server is configured to use a case-insensitive collation by default and that may be why you are unaware of the issue. A column or a database or a server can be configured to use an arbitrary collation, including a case-sensitive one. [See this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/22153) (4 statements, but only 3 matches) for an illustration of how a collation affects the result of a predicate that's dealing with strings. Read up on collations in SQL Server to learn more.